# Unable to type into input text field using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im usign the create-react-app to create a website for a uni assignment and I'm having a bit of trouble getting the input text field to work. I cant seem to type into the text field when I click on it and Im not sure what Ive done wrong as I'm not getting any errors that indicate something is wrong.

The basic idea behind the input text field is when a user enters a search term if it matches an article (within a json file) it will load that data into the News, VideoBox and EventsBox components which is then displayed in Main.

From what I can tell the News, VideoBox and EventsBox are loading correctly as it display 'Not available' when no article is found. Not sure if Im missing something somewhere which is preveting me from typing in the text field? Below is the code for the splash screen which has search input field -

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import NewsLibrary from "./NewsLibrary.json";
import News from "./News";
import VideoBox from "../Aside/VideoBox";
import EventsBox from "./EventsBox";

const SplashWindow = () => {

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

    const [foundArticle, setFoundArticle] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() =>{
        document.querySelector('.splash-window').classList.add('fade-in');
    }, []);

    //console.log(NewsLibrary);

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!searchTerm) {
            setErrorMessage('Please Enter a search term');
            setFoundArticle(false);
            setShowContent(false);
            return;
        }

        const foundArticle = NewsLibrary.find((article) =>

        article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );

        if (foundArticle) {
            setErrorMessage('');
            setShowContent(true);
            setFoundArticle(foundArticle);
        } else {
            setErrorMessage('No Matching Article Found');
            setShowContent(false);
            setFoundArticle(null);
        }

        
    };
   

return (
    <>
    {!showContent && (
        <div className="splash-window fade-out">
            <div className="splash-content">
             <h1>Welcome To Future Sports!</h1>

              <p>
              To begin in the search box below search any sporting event you would to learn more about.
              Or if your not sure what you want you can always type in /Random to be surprised!
              </p>

             <Form onSubmit={handleSearch} className="search-form">
              <div className="search-group">
             <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter your Search Query" className="search-input" name="searchTerm" value={searchTerm} onChange={(e) => 
             setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
             }/>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="splashSearchButton">Search</Button>
           </div>
          </Form>
         {errorMessage && <Alert variant="danger">{errorMessage}</Alert>}
         </div>
        </div>
    )}
    {showContent && foundArticle && (
        <>
        <News article={foundArticle} />
        <VideoBox article={foundArticle} />
        <EventsBox article={foundArticle} />
        </>
    )}
    </>
);
}; //const splash window end


export default SplashWindow;
```

My suspicion is it might be because of this code for the Main.js but Im unsure why it would be preventing me from typing anything into the text field

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ContactUs from "./ContactUs"
import PhotoGallery from "./PhotoGallery";
import News from "./News";
import EventsBox from "./EventsBox";
import SplashWindow from "./SplashWindow"
import NewsLibrary from "./NewsLibrary"


const Main = () => {

    const [foundNewsArticle, setFoundNewsArticle] = useState(null);
    const [foundEventsArticle, setFoundEventsArticle] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {

    // Simulating API fetch with a delay of 1 second

    const fetchData = () => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            setFoundNewsArticle(NewsLibrary);
            setFoundEventsArticle(NewsLibrary);
            }, 1000);
            };
        
            fetchData();
            }, []);

    const handleSetFoundArticle = (article) => {
        setFoundNewsArticle(article);
        setFoundEventsArticle(article);
    }; 

    return (
        <div className="MainSection">
            <ContactUs />
            <PhotoGallery />
            <>
            <div>
             <h3>News Component</h3>
             <SplashWindow setFoundArticle={handleSetFoundArticle} />
             {foundNewsArticle && <News article={foundNewsArticle} />}
            </div>
            
            <div>
             <h3>Events Component</h3>
             <SplashWindow setFoundArticle={handleSetFoundArticle} />
             {foundEventsArticle && <EventsBox article={foundEventsArticle} />}
            </div>
            </>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour of the Form is to refresh each time you type. Create a function to capture the text and add e.preventDefault to it. For example:

```
    const handleChange = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault(), 
       setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
    }
```

Then you can add it to you input like this:

```
 <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter your Search Query" className="search-input" name="searchTerm" value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

I think you may not need the onChange, maybe this works:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import NewsLibrary from "./NewsLibrary.json";
import News from "./News";
import VideoBox from "../Aside/VideoBox";
import EventsBox from "./EventsBox";

const SplashWindow = () => {

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

    const [foundArticle, setFoundArticle] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() =>{
        document.querySelector('.splash-window').classList.add('fade-in');
    }, []);

    //console.log(NewsLibrary);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const searchTerm = e.target.value; 

        if (!searchTerm) {
            setErrorMessage('Please Enter a search term');
            setFoundArticle(false);
            setShowContent(false);
            return;
        }

        const foundArticle = NewsLibrary.find((article) =>

        article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );

        if (foundArticle) {
            setErrorMessage('');
            setShowContent(true);
            setFoundArticle(foundArticle);
        } else {
            setErrorMessage('No Matching Article Found');
            setShowContent(false);
            setFoundArticle(null);
        }

        
    };
   

return (
    <>
    {!showContent && (
        <div className="splash-window fade-out">
            <div className="splash-content">
             <h1>Welcome To Future Sports!</h1>

              <p>
              To begin in the search box below search any sporting event you would to learn more about.
              Or if your not sure what you want you can always type in /Random to be surprised!
              </p>

             <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="search-form">
              <div className="search-group">
             <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter your Search Query" className="search-input" name="searchTerm"/>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="splashSearchButton">Search</Button>
           </div>
          </Form>
         {errorMessage && <Alert variant="danger">{errorMessage}</Alert>}
         </div>
        </div>
    )}
    {showContent && foundArticle && (
        <>
        <News article={foundArticle} />
        <VideoBox article={foundArticle} />
        <EventsBox article={foundArticle} />
        </>
    )}
    </>
);
}; //const splash window end


export default SplashWindow;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Should I have changed anything else? The handleChange is showing as declared but never read? Sorry still a bit new to this

Comment: hmm I tried that but Im getting an error saying:

Line 27:14:  'e' is not defined           no-undef
Line 36:46:  'searchTerm' is not defined  no-undef

This line of code relies on searchTerm and Im not sure how to replace?

`article.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())`

Comment: My bad sorry. e is not defined because in the function parameter was 'event' and then in the conditional was e.target.value (it should have been event.target.value). Then searchTerm was undefined because the state was deleted. I have made a few changes, please try and let me know.